# How can I express GetDate() and DateAdd() methods in EF Core and LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using SQL Server and Entity Framework Core 2. I have the following SQL query which (in SQL Server Management Studio) correctly gives me the measurements that were added the previous hour (to the measurements table):

```
SELECT id, [timestamp] 
FROM measurement 
WHERE
  dateADD(MINUTE, 60, [timestamp]) > getdate()
```

This works well. But now I'd like to write this query in LINQ using EF Core 2.
Of course I could write the following code:

```
dbContext
   .Measurement
   .Include(m => m.Section)
   .GroupBy(m => m.Section, (section, m) => new Section
    {
       Name = section.Name,
       CustomerId = section.CustomerId,
       MostRecentMeasurement = m.Max(z => z.Timestamp)
    })
   .Where(x => x.MostRecentMeasurement > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
   .ToList();
```

but this has the following drawbacks:

- DateTime.Now cannot be translated to SQL hence this will be evaluated at the client which does not perform that well,
- The timezone at the client differs from the database server timezone, needing extra complexity and computation.

How can I express the query in EF Core such that it can be completely translated to SQL?

Comment: What exact EF Core version are you on? `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)` perfectly translates to `DATEADD(hour, -1.0E0, GETDATE())` in the latest EF Core 2.2.3

Comment: I am using 2.1.8. I was triggered by the log message: "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ({from Measurement z in [x] select [z].Timestamp => Max()} > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally." This is also the case after upgrading to 2.2.3

Comment: May be the problem is `Max` then. I'll take a look when have some time. Meanwhile you could verify that it doesn't happen in "normal" `Where` (w/o `GroupBy` involved)

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce with the provided query. I've tried to reconstruct the entity model, but query gives me both "ignored includes" warning and "must be reducible node" exception. Removing the `Include` and changing `GroupBy(m => m.Section` to `GroupBy(m => new { m.Section.Name, m.Section.CustomerId }` allows me to run it, and it's fully translated to SQL. So to find the concrete issue with your code, we need [mcve], but the general answer to the original question is `GETDATE()` => `DateTime.Now` and `DateAdd` => `DateTime.AddXyz` (`Xyz`: `Hours`, `Minutes` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) perfectly translates to DATEADD(hour, -1.0E0, GETDATE()) in EF Core 5.0.8.

(Note, I reproduced the comment by Ivan Stoev because it answered a similar question I had.)